# Excel copying a sheet to another workbook - need named ranges to sync to 2nd workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

I have a template workbook with multiple sheets, and I added a sheet to the template which includes formulas that refer to cells / named ranges on the other sheets within the workbook.
When I copy/paste this new sheet into existing instances of the template workbook, all the cell/formula references remain pointed to the template workbook. I need them to align with the workbook into which they've been pasted (and already has all the same named ranges, etc).

So... how to paste a sheet into a different workbook and have the formulas point to cells in the **destination ** workbook rather than the source? I'd prefer to avoid a VBA solution, but will go there if needed. Thanks!

The un-named cells are manageable, I can just search/replace in the formulas to remove [Template.xlsm], although I'd prefer to avoid this step. But can't find a way to do this with named cells other than going one by one through the Name Manager, which is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly the dynamics of your sheet without a picture or a link to a file, but try this:

1. Create a duplicate source template. We are going to be manipulating this template, so please use only the backup file.
2. For the sheet that you want to copy over from your source to your destination file, hit Ctrl H to open up the search and replace box. In the "Find what", type in the = sign only. Do not put the = sign within quotes like "=".
3. In the "Replace with" field type in any character e.g. ^ (I chose this character specifically since it is seldom used in any file). Make sure to hit the REPLACE ALL button
4. Now you should see all your formulas should have transformed into text with your character ^ in front of it
5. Copy this sheet over to your destination file.
6. In your destination file, press Ctrl H again to bring up the search and replace box.
7. In the "Find What" field, put in your character ^ and in the "Replace With" field put in = without any quotations. Again, make sure to hit the Replace all button that sits on the bottom left of the dialog box.
8. Your formulas should point towards the internal workbook references

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks very much for the thoughtful reply - this will definitely work for my application. This seemed like the sort of thing that Excel should have built-in, so I assumed I was missing a check box, but this will get the job done.